# Pointer Printing Issue

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to get the code to print " 1000 100 10 1" but keep getting "100 10 1 0." Any ideas as to why this is occurring? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    int *ptr;
    ptr = arr;

    *ptr = arr[0] + 1;                   // set arr[0] to 1
    * ( ptr + 1 ) = arr[ 0 ] * 10;      // set arr[1] to 10
    * ( ptr + 2 ) = arr[ 0 ] * 100;     // set arr[2] to 100
    * ( ptr + 3 ) = arr[ 0 ] * 1000;     // set arr[3] to 1000

    cout << "arr[4] = { " << arr[0] << ", " << arr[1] << ", " << arr[2] << ", " << arr[3] << " }" << endl;
    ptr += 3;
    while (ptr >= arr)
    {
        ptr--;
        cout << " " << *ptr;    
    }
    cout << endl;
    return( 0 );

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr += 3` means you are pointing to `arr[3]` but you do `ptr--` before using the address so your printing actually starts at `arr[2]`

The end condition is also dangerous as it sets `ptr` to an address that you "don't own". In theory you are safe because you never use it, but it is still dangerous practice to have pointers with bad values floating around...

I would make it:

```
ptr += 3; // ptr still points to valid memory
while (ptr >= arr)
{
    cout << " " << *ptr;   
    ptr--; // ptr decremented after use so print starts at arr[3] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You moved the pointer to the last element and then get it back to previous element before printing.

Also note that moving pointer back beyond the first element invokes *undefined behavior*.

Try this:

```
ptr += 4; // move the pointer one element after the last element (this is allowed unless you dereference it)
while (ptr > arr) // use > instead of >=
{
    ptr--;
    cout << " " << *ptr;    
}
```

instead of

```
ptr += 3;
while (ptr >= arr)
{
    ptr--;
    cout << " " << *ptr;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ptr = arr;
> ```

`ptr` points to the first element

> ```
> ptr += 3;
> ```

Now it points to the fourth element at index 3; the last index where value is 1000.

> ```
> while (ptr >= arr)
> ```

We enter the loop.

> ```
> ptr--;
> ```

We now point to the third element, at index 2; where value is 100.

> ```
> cout << " " << *ptr;
> ```

We print the value, which is 100.

---

If you want to start printing from the last element of the array, you need to get the value from the pointer when it points to the last element; not after you've decremented the pointer.